# OpenBSD Remote Desktop

Tags: openbsd, remote-desktop

Does OpenBSD have a built-in [remote desktop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_desktop_software) server? If not, what is the most preferred remote desktop server people run on OpenBSD?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Remote desktops are useful for graphic environments.  The only graphic environment for OpenBSD is X11.  You can run X11 applications through `ssh`, or you can run a local X11 server and tell an OpenBSD client to connect to it.

Comment: Just exploring my options :) I was hoping for something that uses a standard protocol like RDP, VNC, or similar because I want to connect from my ChromeBox.

Comment: No, you don't want to connect to OpenBSD through RDP or VNC.  A `ssh` client should be good enough.

Comment: I have nothing against SSH. What I don't like is remote X11. I also have nothing against the the terminal (I use one all day). I just want a nice way to mess around with GUI apps on OpenBSD remotely.

Comment: There is a way that uses standard protocol: X11. What do you have against it? It's the native remote desktop protocol on Unix.

Answer (score 3):

Clear answer: YES, but you have to configure it.

As any unix like system using X you can use Xdmcp
- you have to allow your X chooser, such as GDM or KDM to accept XDMCP connections
- then you open a graphical client or just a terminal: 
`$ X -query your.servers.ip.address`

Alternatively you can always install and run: VNC server

Comment: ... however, X is terribly slow, and should be encapsulated in ssh tunnel. TightVNC works well, just don’t use a WM with animations.